# How to find the integral of $(1-|\tau|)\cos(\omega\tau)e^{-j\omega\tau}$

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics

I have a function that need calculate the integral. Could you help me to find it. Thank you so much
$$f(\omega)=\int_{-1}^1(1-|\tau|)\cos(\omega\tau)e^{-j\omega\tau}d\tau$$
where $\omega$ is constant.

As suggestion of Dirk and Anglego Rendina. I can rewrite as
$$f(\omega) = \int_{-1}^0(1+\tau)\cos(\omega(-\tau))e^{-j\omega\tau}d\tau + \int_{0}^1(1-\tau)\cos(\omega\tau)e^{-j\omega\tau} d\tau$$
$$\implies f(\omega) = \int_{-1}^0(1+\tau)\cos(\omega\tau)e^{-j\omega\tau}d\tau + \int_{0}^1(1-\tau)\cos(\omega\tau)e^{-j\omega\tau}d\tau$$
How about the next step?

Comment: Split the integral in two, where $\tau$ is positive and negative.

Comment: You can. The $\tau$ on the left is not the $\tau$ on the right, he's defining a constant function.

Comment: @AngeloRendina: If he's integrating over $\tau$ in the RHS, then $\tau$ can only be a dummy variable. So it should be a function of $\omega$ not of $\tau$.

Comment: @AngeloRendina and Jean-Claude Arbaut: I mistaken. It must be function of $\omega$

Comment: I also assume $f$ is function of $omega$. I was just stating that what's written's not *wrong*.

Comment: OK. Let see my update. Please guide me the next step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a response to the edited question, where the factor $e^{-i \omega \tau}$ has been added. I originally posted this in reply to another identical question written by the OP, not realizing that it was a duplicate of this one.

---

You are using $\omega$ for two different purposes: one as a constant in $\cos(\omega \tau)$, and the other as the argument of $f(\omega)$. You should use a different letter for one of these. I will take the liberty of writing $f(u)$ instead of $f(\omega)$. Then the integral becomes
$$f(u) = \int_{-1}^{1}(1-|\tau|)\cos(\omega \tau) e^{-i u \tau} d\tau$$
We can use Euler's identity $e^{-i u \tau} = \cos(u \tau) - i \sin(u\tau)$ to obtain
$$f(u) = \int_{-1}^{1}(1-|\tau|)\cos(\omega \tau) \cos(u\tau) d\tau -
i\int_{-1}^{1}(1-|\tau|)\cos(\omega \tau) \sin(u\tau) d\tau$$
Note that $1-|\tau|$, $\cos(\omega \tau)$, and $\cos(u \tau)$ are all even functions of $\tau$, and $\sin(u \tau)$ is an odd function of $\tau$. Therefore, the integrand of the first integral is an even function, and the integrand of the second integral is an odd function. Since we are integrating over $[-1,1]$, this implies that the second integral is zero, and the first one becomes
$$f(u) = 2\int_{0}^{1}(1-|\tau|)\cos(\omega \tau) \cos(u\tau) d\tau$$
Since we are now integrating over positive values of $\tau$ only, we no longer need the absolute values:
$$f(u) = 2\int_{0}^{1}(1-\tau)\cos(\omega \tau) \cos(u\tau) d\tau$$
Finally, we can use the trig identity $\cos(a)\cos(b) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(a+b) + \cos(a-b))$ to obtain
$$f(u) = \int_{0}^{1}(1-\tau)\cos((\omega + u)\tau) d\tau + 
\int_{0}^{1}(1-\tau)\cos((\omega - u)\tau) d\tau$$
so if you know how to integrate
$$\int_{0}^{1}(1-\tau)\cos(a \tau) d\tau$$
then that takes care of both integrals. This is easily done: we can rewrite it as
$$\int_{0}^{1}\cos(a \tau) d\tau - \int_{0}^{1}\tau\cos(a \tau) d\tau$$
The first integral is elementary, and the second yields nicely to integration by parts:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\cos(a \tau) d\tau = \frac{1}{a}\sin(a)$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\tau\cos(a \tau) d\tau = \frac{1}{a}\sin(a) +\frac{1}{a^2}\cos(a) - \frac{1}{a^2}$$
so
$$\int_{0}^{1}(1-\tau)\cos(a \tau) d\tau = \frac{1}{a^2} (1 - \cos(a))$$
Plugging in $a = \omega - u$ and $a = \omega + u$, we obtain
$$f(u) = \frac{1}{(\omega + u)^2} (1 - \cos(\omega + u)) + \frac{1}{(\omega - u)^2} (1 - \cos(\omega - u))$$
provided that $u \neq \pm \omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Split the integral in $\int_{-1}^0$ and $\int_0^{1}$ and use that $|\tau| = -\tau$ in the former and $|\tau| = \tau$ in the latter integral.

Comment: That would cause confusion between $f(\omega)$ and the new $f$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\wg}{\omega}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}$
$$\int\limits_{-1}^1(1-|t|)\cos(\wg t)\dd t=\int\limits_{-1}^0(1+t)\cos(\wg t)\dd t+\int\limits_0^1(1-t)\cos(\wg t)\dd t,$$
as alreandy suggested by others. Then I will work only on the first integral, as the other is very similar.
$$\int\limits_{-1}^0(1+t)\cos(\wg t)\dd t=\int\limits_{-1}^0\cos(\wg t)\dd t+\int\limits_{-1}^0t\cos(\wg t)\dd t\underset{y=\wg t}{=}\int\limits_{-\wg}^0\cos y\cdot\frac{\dd y}{\wg}+\int\limits_{-\wg}^0\frac{y}{\wg}\cos y\cdot\frac{\dd y}{\wg}.$$
Let's look at the second piece now. That can be integrated by parts, meaning we get $\frac{y}{\wg^2}\sin y|_{-\wg}^0=\frac{1}{\wg}\sin(\wg)$ and we have to subtract the integral over $[-\wg,0]$ of $\frac{\sin y}{\wg^2}\dd y=-\frac{\cos y}{\wg^2}\Big|_{-\wg}^0=-\frac{1}{\wg^2}+\frac{\cos(\wg)}{\wg^2}$. So the second piece is:
$$\frac{\sin(\wg)}{\wg}+\frac{1-\cos(\wg)}{\wg^2}.$$
The first piece is a simple integral of a cosine, so I guess you can do that. The second integral above is done similarly, so I leave it to you to modify the steps above to adapt them to the other integral.

Comment: You have forgotten the factor $e^{-i\omega\tau}$

Comment: @Michael: The OP added the factor $e^{-i\omega \tau}$ in an edit.

Comment: Yes, I see that, it happened about 1 hour after my answer. I won't edit my answer though, since the extra term causes the calculations – at least at a first glance to me – to be rather more complex, and yours, @Bungo, seems to have already fully addressed the (new) question. And I say "seems" since I haven't yet read through it with enough attention to be sure.